# Covariant derivative of a pseudoriemannian metric in coordinates

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, solution-verification, tensors

I am studying the notion of covariant derivative in order to define what is the Levi civita connection.
I know that given a pseudo riemannian manifold there exists one only connection $\nabla$ that is METRIC and SYMMETRIC and this is the so called Levi Civita connection.
Now in order to undesrtand all the notions involved in this proposition I have to consider that a connection is metric if $\nabla g=0$, where $g$ is the pseudoriemannian metric on the general manifold.
Now in coordinates I can write:
$$\nabla g=g_{ij;k}dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes dx^k$$
Now my problem is in determining $g_{ij;k}$, or better I don't know if my attempt is correct.

$\textbf{My work:}$
$$g_{ij;k}=\nabla_{\partial_k} g(\partial_{i},\partial_j)=\partial_k g(\partial_i, \partial_j)-g(\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_i, \partial_j)-g(\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_j, \partial_i)=g_{ij,k}-g(\Gamma_{ki}^s\partial_s, \partial_j)-g(\partial_i, \Gamma_{kj}^s\partial_s)=$$ $$=g_{ij,k}-\Gamma_{ki}^sg_{sj}- \Gamma_{kj}g_{is} $$
Is this correct as the final expression for $g_{ij;k}$?

Comment: I think $\nabla g$ should be a tensor of rank  3

Comment: Oh yes Thanks now I correct the mistake! But this give me an error only on the missing $dx^k$...the final formula is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's correct or not, it looks right but I don't want to mislead you

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.

Comment: @Deane thanks for the confirmation!